# Firebase (storage/unknown) error when posting images | React

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I want to post an image to Firebase Storage. My React app is on Netlify.

Firebase Config file.
The environment variables are set on Netlify.

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getStorage } from "firebase/storage"

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
    authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
    projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
    storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
    messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
    appId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const storage = getStorage(app)
```

This is where I am uploading the image

```
import { storage } from '../../firebase';
import { ref, uploadBytes, getDownloadURL } from "firebase/storage"

const uploadToFirebase = async (newPost) => {
        if (postImage == null) return;
        const imageRef = ref(storage, `images/${postImage.name + v4()}`)

        await uploadBytes(imageRef, postImage)
        const url = await getDownloadURL(imageRef)
        newPost.post.image = url
    }
```

when i click on the upload button on the site, i get these errors

```
POST https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/***/o?name=images%2FScreenshot%20(5).pngfc61b7f6-da0d-40f3-a3e5-864e27810503 404
```

```
Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Firebase Storage: An unknown error occurred, please check the error payload for server response. (storage/unknown)
```

The error payload says 404 not found

Firebase Storage Rules

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

PS: This code works locally

I thought there might be a problem with the environment variables so tried hardcoding them the problem persisted.

Comment: Use Try catch inside your code and see what happens?

Comment: @GulshanAggarwal If you meant to use try- catch in uploadToFirebase functinon, I tried it, the error is still the same.

Comment: what's the exact error?

Comment: @GulshanAggarwal https://imgur.com/CJp9ydd

Comment: Where the postImage comes from?

Comment: because there might be a slight error we need to take care of all things.

Comment: postimage is a state which holds the actual image taken as input from user